# Is This Ticket is refundable or not?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines

CANCELLATIONS

```
BEFORE DEPARTURE
  CHARGE USD 100.00 FOR CANCEL/REFUND.
  WAIVED FOR DEATH OF PASSENGER OR FAMILY MEMBER.

AFTER DEPARTURE
  TICKET IS NON-REFUNDABLE IN CASE OF CANCEL/REFUND.
  WAIVED FOR DEATH OF PASSENGER.

ANY TIME
  CHARGE USD 150.00 FOR NO-SHOW.
  WAIVED FOR DEATH OF PASSENGER OR FAMILY MEMBER.
                                              PAGE  1/11
```

>
In this fare rule Pax flight is on 26feb18  pax is no-show , and also this ticket is one way from EBB to DMM by MS, Ticket status also open for use
please give me suggestion about whether it is refundable or not?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this fare rule Pax flight is on 26feb18 pax is no-show

**It is no longer refundable**. It was refundable before departure but since the flight has already departed it is too late given these fare conditions.

```
AFTER DEPARTURE
  TICKET IS NON-REFUNDABLE IN CASE OF CANCEL/REFUND.
```

**However**, as noted by [@jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110425/is-this-ticket-is-refundable-or-not/110427#comment268090_110427) below, you may still be able to reschedule this ticket after paying $150 fee and any possible fare difference.

Comment: It's not refundable, but per the no-show rule, it sounds like you can still move it to another day by paying $150 (and potentially some fare difference).